# Which type of Stripe Connect user suitable for a marketplace platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-connect

I am working for a donation platform using Rails 5.1.1. Here mainly two types of user - i) Donors, ii) Organizations.

Donor can donate any amount to a specific organizations.

Organization can get their donations (cut off the platform fee). And organization owner can transfer their money to their bank account or Debit card.

For above functionalities i want to use Stripe Connect. I found stripe connect has three types of user (Standard, express and custom).

So my application scenario, Which user type is suitable for organization to manage their activities ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to create charges in stripe connect. Looks like you would need to go with Stripe conect's `Creating Separate Charges and Transfers`

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers

The only limitation is that it is currently available only in US and Europe. You can find more information on Stripe's documentation link above.